# Displaying information from an object sent from a servlet to a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, object, servlets, jstl

I can successful get the object from the servlet to the jsp page but can quite figure how to get the individual elements in that object to display, I tried to get the JSTL tag lib working as shown below but to no avail. I Would be very grateful for any help on this I know its only something small as the object is there on the jsp.

Also, Is this the best method? What are the good alternatives?

Servlet to supply Welcome.jsp

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    if (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser") != null) {
        user = (User) session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser");
        userData = (User) ProfileDAO.displayUserProfile(user);

        request.setAttribute("userData", userData);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("LoginFailure.html");
    }
}
```

Welcome.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    :
    :
    :
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome to BLAHBLAH.COM

<%
    Object userData = request.getAttribute("userData");

%>
<table>
    <c:choose items="${userData}" var="userData">
        <tr>
            <td>${userData.name}</td>
            <td>${userData.information}</td>
            <td>${userData.address1}</td>
       </tr>
    </c:choose>
</table>

<p>userData></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Scriptlets in jsp is not recommended.We need to use

1.El expression
   or

2.TagLibrary

The problem with your code is you are using a scriptlet in jsp which is not necessory at all

```
  Object userData = request.getAttribute("userData");
```

because  `userData` object is already available in request scope with this code

```
request.setAttribute("userData", userData);
```

3.You can print the values of userData object directly by using El expressions like this

```
            <td>${userData.name}</td>
            <td>${userData.information}</td>
            <td>${userData.address1}</td>
```

4.You can also print the values using jstl which is always recommended approach

```
  <c:out value="${userData.name}"/>
  <c:out value="${userData.information}"/>
  <c:out value="${userData.address1}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure If you would want JSTL as a requirement, but here is a code sample that should work in JSP

```
<%
     User userData = (User)request.getAttribute("userData");
%>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td><%= userData.name %></td>
       <td><%= userData.information %></td>
       <td><%= userData.address1 %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```